# How to disable or customize side menu on media modal

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to implement a WordPress widget like a built-in Image widget.

My image select modal has unnecessary menus on left side(e.g. Create Gallery, Create Audio Playlist)

[my modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmdX7.png)

Here is the Image Widget created by Modern Tribe.
It has no side menu and no media type selector.

[image widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGuwp.png)

How can I remove side menu and disable the media type selector?

Below is my Javascript code:

```
var frame = wp.media({
    title: MyWidget.frame_title,
    multiple: false,
    frame: "post",
    library: { type: 'image' },
    button: {text: MyWidget.button_text}
});

frame.open();
```

PHP:

```
// functions.php(not as a plugin)
public function load_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-widget-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/widget-about.js',
    array('jquery', 'media-upload', 'media-views') );
}
```

Comment: Do you solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

WP media frame settings object have no property to hide left menu, i spend some time to find it, and it not exist. If you don't want to show this menu for your users you can hide it with simple css styling, like so:

```
.media-menu {
    display: none;
}
.media-modal-content .media-frame-title,
.media-modal-content  .media-frame-router,
.media-modal-content  .media-frame-content,
.media-modal-content  .media-frame-toolbar {
    left: 0;
}
```